# Trying to change the text position in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making four buttons (`input type="button"`) in html and want them to run function on click but nothing happening.

the html code is:

```html
<div id="newtext" style="position:absolute; top:100px;">
    <p>this is Text</p>
</div>
<form>
    <input type="button" name="moveLayer" value="move Left" onclick="move('left');">
    <input type="button" name="moveLayer" value="move Right" onclick="move('right');">
    <input type="button" name="moveLayer" value="move Up" onclick="move('up'); ">
    <input type="button" name="moveLayer" value="move Down" onclick="move('down'); ">
</form>
```

and the script is :

```js
function move(direction) {
    var layerText = document.getElementByID("newtext");

    switch(direction) {
    
    case "left":
        layerText.style.left=50;
        break;
        
    case "right":
        layerText.style.right=150;
        break;
    
    case "up":
        layerText.style.up=50;
        break;
    case "down":
        layerText.style.down=150;
        break;
    default:
    it is not working;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Replace `getElementByID` with `getElementById`..and also mention unit i.e "px". For example, `layerText.style.left = 50 + "px";` .check errors in console.

Comment: yes still not working :(

Comment: melomane, what is `it is not working` part in default? try to keep some alert or console instead of that to test it.. and also check errors in the console of your browser developer tool.

Comment: yeah..after correcting defalt it is working and also i have made one more mistake that layerText.style.up while there must be top not up.. :p thanks a lot Mr_Green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (there's no such thing as style.up and style.down):

```
function move(direction) {
    var layerText = document.getElementById("newtext");

    switch (direction) {

        case "left":
            layerText.style.left = "50px";
            break;

        case "right":
            layerText.style.left = "150px";
            break;

        case "up":
            layerText.style.top = "50px";
            break;

        case "down":
            layerText.style.top = "150px";
            break;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GE3C5/2/

Answer (score 1):

```js
layerText.style.up=50;
                 ^

layerText.style.down=150;
                 ^
```

no property up and down. use top and bottom instead;

```js
default:
    it is not working;
```

may cause syntax error